# Retrieving records with _____________ relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I have 5 tables.

User tabel => This table stores the data of users.
Exam table => This table stores the data of exams.
Feeds table => This table stores the data of feeds.
Exam_User_Pivot table => This table stores the data of users and exams means the user_id and exam_id.
Exam_Feed_Pivot table => This table stores the data of exams and feeds means the exam_id and feed_id.

**Now, I want to retrieve the no. of users per each feed ?**

I have three models :

**1. User Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'uid';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'phone',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function exams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(exam::class, 'exam_user', 'user_id', 'exam_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }
}
```

**2. Exam Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class exam extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'eid';

    protected $fillable = [
        'exam_name',
    ];
}
```

**3. Feed Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Feed extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'fid';

    protected $fillable = [
        'feed_type', 'title', 'description', 'feed_media', 'source',
    ];

    public function feedexams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(exam::class, 'exam_feed', 'feed_id', 'exam_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }
}
```

> - Users have many-to-many relationship with Exams
> - Feeds have many-to-many relationship with Exams

**I want to retrieve the no. of users per each feed And I don't know which relationship can be use ?**

Comment: You can use [relationship count](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI But how ? I tried but not succeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first add the following two functions to your Exam Model.

Add to Exam model:

```
 public function feeds() {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Feed')->withTimeStamps(); // 
  }

 public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimeStamps(); //
  }
```

I want to retrieve the no. of users per each feed .....

The reasoning  is based on the following three points:

1. get the feed,
2. then get exams of that feed (one feed has many exams)
3. then get users in each of these exams (here we will use a loop to ensure we count users of each exam from 2 above)

Loop through all feeds as:

```
 foreach(App\Feed::all() as $feed) { 
 //here you are accessing all related exams using the function feedexams() that you have created in the feeds model
 
   $exams  = $feed->feedexams();  

 //because each exam will have its own users, we need a way to count the users for each exam, and finally ensure we sum or count all of them. we create a counter called $user_per_feed_count to keep or remember the users count as we loop through all exams. 
 //Finally we will output this counter which will have the total of all users belonging to exams which belong to the feed.

   $users_count = 0; //initialize a users counter with zero

   foreach($exams as $exam) {
    //now we update our counter by adding the number of users for each exam
    $users_count +=  $exam->users()->count();
   }
   //HERE IS YOUR no. of users per each feed.
  echo "Feed " . $feed->name . "has " . $users_count . " users"; 
 }
```

Expected output will be as follows ...

Feed myfeed has 10 users

Feed otherfeed has 38 users

Now to test it, just go to your   routes/web.php    and add the following code

```
Route::get('getusers',  function () {
    foreach (App\Feed::all() as $feed) {
        $exams  = $feed->feedexams();
        $users_count = 0; //initialize a users counter with zero
        foreach ($exams as $exam) {
        //$users_count +=  $exam->users()->count();
        $users_count +=  $exam->has('users') ? $exam->users()->count() : 0;

    }
        echo "Feed " . $feed->name . "has " . $users_count . " users";
    }
});
```

then open your browser and  type this link:

http://YOUR_PROJECT_NAME_HERE/getusers       and press enter:

Note: Replace YOUR_PROJECT_NAME_HERE with your actual project name. Make sure you have some exams,users, and feeds already in your database.
MY RESULTS

[image: exam_user table]

[image: exam_feed table]

[image: final result]

Comment: Can you just write it in more descriptive bcz I unable to understand.

Comment: After adding that two functions in Exam model, In which file I have to add rest of the code?

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain where to put the code. But you can also put the code in your controllers or even on your blade views. Ensure your database has some data in the tables.

Comment: I tried your code and it is running but showig the wrong output. It showig only 4 users for all feeds.

Comment: Great. Let me create a simple database quickly and test.

Comment: Sure, make tables like me and test it.

Comment: I have created and tested. Seems to work fine. I have added pictures of my test results. I have edited the line  
$users_count +=  $exam->has('users') ? $exam->users()->count() : 0;   
// so that it doesnt throw errors for exams that dont have users

Comment: Can we connect via other medium like mail or whatsapp....

Comment: If it works, please remember to upvote my answer as correct.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Get all of the user for the feed. define in Feed Model
 */
public function feedUsers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(App\Models\Exam::class App\Models\User::class);
}
$feeds = App\Feed::all();
foreach($feeds as $feed){
    echo $feed->feedUsers->count();
}
```